# Possible to pass a changing array to a stateless component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So let's say I have a stateless component. I want this component to
display a static title but also map through an array that's 
being passed in. I only want to do it this way due to styling
issues. Is this possible or is there another way to go about this?

Thanks!

```
const ListTitle = ({ style, title, icon, checkedItems, onPressExpand }) => (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPressExpand}>
        <View style={ [style, baseStyles.touchableList] }>
          <Text>{title}</Text>
          {icon}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {
        checkedItems.map((item, i) => (
          <View>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </View>
        ))
      }

    </View>
)
```

`checkedItems` is the array I want to pass in. `{checkedItems}.map` doesn't look right but neither does the way I tried. I'm starting to think this isn't possible but wanted to know what others have to say.

Comment: Did you try this? Seems OK to me. Do you get some sort of error?

Comment: You can't just move the {} containing your checkItems map right below your first *inner View component?

Comment: @bennygenel i'm getting a 'undefined is not an object (evaluating `checkedItems.map`)

Comment: Are you sure that checkedItems contain an array of item? Can you do a console.log  please

Comment: @bennygenel i get an infinite loop of `undefined`

Comment: also the way i'm using it is `<ListTitle checkedItems={this.state.itemsChecked} />` which is an array in the state

Comment: can you please create a [mcve] in [snack.expo.io](https://snack.expo.io/)

Comment: it works in the snack! i'm going to keep on adding items from my project bit by bit and see where it breaks. thanks! https://snack.expo.io/S1PhnkmfX